# Django problem with authenticated in html

Tags: django

why when I click on the link on the profile of another user, the option to log in is highlighted in the top menu, as if I had not authenticated (in the navbar it is possible to log in, the condition {% if user.is_authenticated%} is written there. If I open another page again everything is fine, the user is authenticated.

navbar

```
 <div class="">
  {% if user.is_authenticated %}
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="{% url 'account' %}">
    <img
      src="{{user.profile.avatar.url}}"
      alt=""
      width="50"
      height="50"
      class="d-inline-block"
    />
  </a>

  {% else %}
  <div class="signin">
    <a
      href="{% url 'login' %}"
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded"
    >
      <div class="mx-auto">login</div>
    </a>
    <a
      href="{% url 'register' %}"
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-success btn-rounded"
    >
      <div class="mx-auto">register</div>
    </a>
  </div>
```

vviews.py

```
def list_users(request):
    users = Profile.objects.all()
    context = {'users':users}
    return render(request, 'profiles/list_users.html', context)




def profile_detail(request, pk):
    user = Profile.objects.get(id=pk)
    context = {'user':user}
    return render(request, 'profiles/profile_detail.html', context)        
enter code here
```

when going to this page, the user is not authenticated

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %} {% block content %}

<div>
  <h1>HELLOOOO</h1>
  {{user.user}}
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

url

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.list_users, name='list_users'),
    path('account/', views.account, name='account'),
    path('profile_detail/<int:pk>/', views.profile_detail, name='profile_detail'),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have passed `user` in the context. This is the user whose profile you are looking at. In the template you check `{% if user.is_authenticated %}` which uses the `user` in the context. Use `request.user` in the template when you want to refer to the current user to prevent such errors.

Comment: Thanks dude, if  i could i would give you 1000 likes